# Single quote in awk

Tags: awk

Would someone please explain what is happening with below `awk` command? if it's no error then why `notme` is not getting print, and why I'm not getting syntax error then for close bracket `...}` need close with quote `...}'`?

```
$ awk '{print "me "$0 '"notme"} <<<"printme"
me printme
```

Then so I would tried this:

```
$ awk '{print "me "$0 '"\"$(date)"\"} <<<"printme-at "
me printme-at Wed Apr 11 16:41:34 DST 2018
```

Or

```
awk '{print '"\"$(date)\""} <<<"run"
Wed Apr 11 16:56:38 DST 2018
```

Which as it shows means I can do everything using shell command substitution.

Is this a bug? Or maybe a special state that I cannot find.

Comment: Correct, but why no syntax error I'm getting? for those who want to know what I'm trying to achieve? I just accidently typed a single quote and I had no close quote for `awk` there `...}`. I also tried to create a file called `notme}` as I found I'm not getting error for unquoted `}`, then did `...cat "notme"} <<<"printme"` and I got syntax error, and when I add `;` in `...; cat "notme"} <<<"printme"` then nothing changed because my `awk` is completely will give syntax error and anything after `;` in shell will consider a separate command, so I go into using `$(...)` within `awk`.

Comment: As a side note, at least GNU Awk has a built-in function [`strftime`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#Time-Functions) that can perform the same task as `$(date)` but without the help of command substitution or other shell features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first one

> ```
> $ awk '{print "me "$0 '"notme"} <<<"printme"
> ```

What's happening here is:

1. The part in single quotes is passed to `awk` verbatim
2. The next part `"notme"}` is parsed by the shell and then passed to `awk` as the resulting string `notme}`
3. `awk` gets to see this:

   ```
   {print "me "$0 notme}
   ```

   Since the `awk` variable `notme` has no value, that's what you get

For the second one

> ```
> $ awk '{print "me "$0 '"\"$(date)"\"} <<<"printme-at "
> me printme-at Wed Apr 11 16:41:34 DST 2018
> ```

I'd be more inclined to write it like this, using an `awk` variable to carry the value of `$(date)`:

```
awk -v date="$(date)" '{print "me "$0 date}' <<<"printme-at "
me printme-at Wed Apr 11 13:43:31 BST 2018
```

You've asked why there is no syntax error in your version of this one. Let's take it apart:

```
# typed at the shell
awk '{print "me "$0 '"\"$(date)"\"} <<<"printme-at "

# prepared for awk
awk '{print "me "$0 "Wed Apr 11 16:41:34 DST 2018"}' <<<"printme-at "

# seen by awk
{print "me "$0 "Wed Apr 11 16:41:34 DST 2018"}
```

The double-quoted string `"\"$(date)\""` is parsed by the shell before `awk` gets anywhere near it, and is evaluated (by the shell) as something like the literal string `"Wed Apr 11 13:43:31 BST 2018"` (including the double-quote marks). I don't see why there needs to be a syntax error as what you have written is valid - although somewhat tortuous to read.

Comment: why no `awk` syntax error `awk '{print "me "$0 '"\"$(date)"\"} <<<"printme-at "` then? also [please read](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437002/single-quote-in-awk#comment789641_437002)

Comment: @αғsнιη Why should there be a syntax error there? Run it in the shell, but use `set -x` first.

Answer (score 2):

The single quote ends the string that delimits the `awk` program in the shell.  `awk` itself will never see it. You then concatenate that initial part of the program with more strings provided by command substitutions and static strings in the shell. This all happens before `awk` has been invoked.

Of course you could use command substitutions to modify a string that later is read by `awk` as its code, but it does not really make for easy to read code, and may be rather fragile with regards to the shell's quoting rules, word splitting etc.

It would be better to just set an `awk` variable in the usual way:

```
awk -v thedate="$(date)" '{ print $0, thedate }'  <<<"something"
```

Comment: hmm, your first sentence make sense to me about the single quote ,

Comment: referring to your first sentence, another thing that I saw is that the single quote insids `awk` should together with at least one of double quotes otherwise it will produce a syntax error again which it makes more difficult to me understand the issue there.